# FLASH/AS3: Getting error on removing child. Parameter child must be non-null

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5, flash-cs6

I'm trying to remove MovieClip but it says Parameter child must be non-null.

This My Script:

To make it in stage, i use:

```
function sayam (e:MouseEvent):void{
    nilai = 8;
    if(nilai == temp) {
    var ssAyam:ayam_mc = new ayam_mc
    stage.addChild(ssAyam);
    ssAyam.x = 350.0;
    ssAyam.y = 330.0;
    ssAyam.width = 170.0;
    ssAyam.height = 170.0;
    ssAyam.instanceName = "Ayam";
    arnam.push("Ayam");
    trace("arnam" +arnam);
    trace(ssAyam.instanceName);
    jual = jual + 4000;
    temp = val[len-(len-len2)]
    len2 = len2 + 1;
    } else {
            money = money - 4000;

        }

    }
```

So, i made 8 functions to make 8 movieclips to display in stage and push them to array.
The Array is "arnam".

and this is my remove code:

```
function deleteBurger() {
                for(var i:Number=arnam.length; i >= 0; i--){
                        removeChild(arnam[i]);
                        arnam.splice(i,1);
                }
            }
```

I've traced my array and it isn't null.

can anybody help me? thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't modify an array in a loop based on this array's length, the behaviour would be unpredictable.

```
for each(var child:Sprite in arnam){
    stage.removeChild(child);
}
arnam = [];
```

Comment: it says the supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.

Comment: maybe you are not on stage, use stage.removeChild

Comment: how to validate? im new here :D

Comment: Just check the tick on the left of this answer.

Answer (score 2):

I like to do this to zero out an array and manipulate the members as I do so:

```
while( arnam.length )
{
    removeChild( arnam.pop() );
}
```

Now, I would use a [Vector](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html) of MovieClips, to strongly type, rather than an Array. And also use contains() to check that the MovieClip is still on stage before trying to remove it :)

Comment: it's same. it says the supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller

Comment: well then you need to get the parent of the MovieClip and call remove() on it. There's a .parent property on any DisplayObject: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#parent

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for(var i:int=arnam.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
                        removeChild(arnam[i]);
                        arnam.splice(i,1);

                }
```

Comment: the error has changed to DisplayObject must be a child if the caller

Comment: Before you remove arnam[i] you could try tracing arnam[i].parent to see where (or if) it HAS been added: trace("arnam["+i+"].parent = "+arnam[i].parent);